# How to show the dialog with MatdialogRef?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, snackbar

I have a service call with for retrieving some project data. And I am using the MatSnackbar.

But I want to show the dialog message when there is something wrong. For example network is down.

So in Google chrome I choose for the option offline. And then I want to see the dialog.

But the dialog is not appearing, but the console message will be printed.

So I have it like this:

```
filterProjects(event, index, item) {
    if (event.checked === true) {
      this.extendedSearchFilterService.filterByProject(item.projectId).subscribe(
        () => {

        },
        error => {
          console.error('Server error when getting the projects', error);
          this.snackBar.open('Er ging iets mis bij het ophalen van de projecten, probeer het later nog een keer', 'Ok');
          this.dialog.close();
        }
      );

      this.datasource.filter = item.name;
    } else {
      this.datasource.filter = '';
    }
  }
```

And I see in the console, this message:

```
list.component.ts:117 Server error when getting the projects HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

zone.js:2969 OPTIONS https://dev-engine.mijnhep.nl/api/medical/organisation/1/Participant/filter-by-project?ProjectId=4f78e0c0-8cd3-4e37-bf62-105f622c483f net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

But the dialog:

```
    this.snackBar.open('Er ging iets mis bij het ophalen van de projecten, probeer het later nog een keer', 'Ok');
```

Will not be appearing.

So how to show also the dialog?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want message you can try putting : `alert("demo message");`

```
error => {
          console.error('Server error when getting the projects', error);
          alert('Er ging iets mis bij het ophalen van de projecten, probeer het later nog een keer', 'Ok');
          this.dialog.close();
        }
```

Hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, oke, that works. But I want of course to use the MatSnackbar with the fancy dialog. Because I also use it in other component. ANd that works.

Comment: But somebody any advice? Would be nice